# Query Returning Id instead of Relationship field

Tags: trigger, soql

Getting some odd results from a query in a `before` trigger context

My Account object has a lookup to a object called `Region__c`. `Region__c` has a lookup to `Division__c`.

When I try to query the Division from the Account, it instead only returns the region id:

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Region__r.Division__c 
   FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.NewMap.Keyset()];
System.debug(accs);
```

> (Account:{Id=0014C000008cL2LQAU, Name=asdas, OwnerId=0053000000BPS4DAAX, Region__c=a0k30000000QnH3AAK})

The only thing I can think of is this is a permissions issue (still would seem like weird behavior), but I've checked Object, FLS, used `without sharing`, and not to mention I'm running as an admin user.

What am I missing?

### Update:

If I query the Division directly from the Region it works fine:

```
for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
   System.debug([SELECT Division__c FROM Region__c WHERE Id = :acc.Region__c]);
}
```

> (Region__c:{Division__c=a1W3A000001dfIGUAY, Id=a0k30000000QnH3AAK})

Comment: Try adding that field in debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you debug the parent query you will get the id of the lookup only.

To get the vale of the child field you have to explicitly output it.

```
Region__r.Division__c
```

Another way is the getSObject method if you need the sObject

```
Region__c tmp = (Region__c)accs.getSObject('Region__r');
System.debug(tmp.Division__c);
```

Note you can only get field explicitly in the query you created the SObject from

Comment: I did not know that... The code isn't working as expected and after debugging I got stuck on the fact that it must have something to do with the value not being there.  Thanks!